# Loading function on scroll or any other event

Tags: javascript

I have added a script dynamically with this function and trying to load it on `scroll` i tried attaching `window.onscroll` event to this function. but didn't work. Any idea?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
});
loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js")
```

my target is to stop loading the script and style until the user scroll. also, it must load only once.

Comment: how are you calling the window.onscroll function?

Comment: Please include the code where you are adding the event listener.

Comment: i just attached window.addEventListener('scroll',

Comment: better edit your question with all the (relevant) code

Comment: done. i don't want to load script untill user scroll

Comment: At first, the only argument passed to an event handler is the event object. You need `function () {loadjscssfile(filename, filetype);}`. Apart from that, you probably don't want to add hundreds of scripts, `scroll` fires multiple times during scrolling, you should create a flag which you can check, or rather remove the scroll listener after it has been used once.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing to window.addEventListener the return value of loadjscssfile. Because of no return statements in loadjscssfile, it's null.
If you want to pass the `foo` function as an argument, use `window.addEventListener("scroll", foo)`. Do not put parentheses after the name of `foo`.

Comment: can you explain more?